# How to access Keycloak Console deployed in Microk8s with the Keycloak Operator. Ingress?

Tags: keycloak, microk8s, kubernetes-operator

I have deployed Keycloak in Microk8s using the keycloak k8s operator
I followed the guide in the keycloak documentation to deploy the operator then deploy a keycloak resource

My keycloak manifest

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: keycloak-orc-poc
spec:
  instances: 1
  db:
    vendor: postgres
    host: <pg host>
    usernameSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: username
    passwordSecret:
      name: keycloak-db-secret
      key: password
    database: keycloak-orc-poc
  http:
    tlsSecret: <my secret>
  hostname:
    hostname: <my host>
```

My Operator generated Ingress

```
$ kubectl describe ingress keycloak-orc-poc-ingress
Name:             keycloak-orc-poc-ingress
Labels:           app=keycloak
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=keycloak-operator
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  keycloak-orc-poc-service:8443 (10.1.170.209:8443)
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  <my host>  
                               keycloak-orc-poc-service:8443 (10.1.170.209:8443)
Annotations:                nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
                            route.openshift.io/termination: passthrough
Events:                     <none>
```

So what is the path to the Keycloak Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked it out

https://{my host}/admin